# How to read from a USB Joystick with C++ and DirectX8 in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, directx, joystick

I need help in reading data from a specific **joystick** when it is connected to a **PC** in which the data read is received by **2019 visual studio c++** pc program. I want it to detect a particular joystick when connected to a PC based on a product ID or something similar, I don't want it just to detect a joystick that's connected. Then, I would obviously like to have it be read from it and display the read data on the console using cout or something similar. Please provide me a complete example as I've looked at many APIs and function prototypes of the **DirectX** library to use and I'm still very lost. Thanks. Below is what I have so far;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <Windows.h>

#define DIRECTINPUT_VERSION 0x0800
#include <dinput.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "dinput8.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dxguid.lib")

LPDIRECTINPUT8 di;
HRESULT hr;
LPDIRECTINPUTDEVICE8 joystick;
OLECHAR* ap;
DIDEVCAPS capabilities;

BOOL CALLBACK
enumCallback(const DIDEVICEINSTANCE* instance, VOID* context)
{
    HRESULT hr;

    // Obtain an interface to the enumerated joystick.
    hr = di->CreateDevice(instance->guidInstance, &joystick, NULL);

    // If it failed, then we can't use this joystick. (Maybe the user unplugged
    // it while we were in the middle of enumerating it.)
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return DIENUM_CONTINUE;
    }

   

    // Stop enumeration. Note: we're just taking the first joystick we get. You
    // could store all the enumerated joysticks and let the user pick.
    return DIENUM_STOP;
}

BOOL CALLBACK
enumAxesCallback(const DIDEVICEOBJECTINSTANCE* instance, VOID* context) {

    HWND hDlg = (HWND)context;

    DIPROPRANGE propRange;
    propRange.diph.dwSize = sizeof(DIPROPRANGE);
    propRange.diph.dwHeaderSize = sizeof(DIPROPHEADER);
    propRange.diph.dwHow = DIPH_BYID;
    propRange.diph.dwObj = instance->dwType;
    propRange.lMin = -1000;
    propRange.lMax = +1000;

    if (FAILED(joystick->SetProperty(DIPROP_RANGE, &propRange.diph))) return DIENUM_STOP;

    return DIENUM_CONTINUE;

}

HRESULT
poll(DIJOYSTATE2* js) {

    HRESULT     hr;

    if (joystick == NULL) {
        return S_OK;
    }

    hr = joystick->Poll();
    if (FAILED(hr)) {

        hr = joystick->Acquire();

        while (hr == DIERR_INPUTLOST) hr = joystick->Acquire();

        if ((hr == DIERR_INVALIDPARAM) || (hr == DIERR_NOTINITIALIZED)) return E_FAIL;

        if (hr == DIERR_OTHERAPPHASPRIO)  return S_OK;
    }

    if (FAILED(hr = joystick->GetDeviceState(sizeof(DIJOYSTATE2), js))) return hr;

    return S_OK;
}

int main() {

    // Create a DirectInput device
    if(FAILED(hr = DirectInput8Create(GetModuleHandle(NULL), DIRECTINPUT_VERSION, IID_IDirectInput8, (VOID**)&di, NULL))) return hr;

    if(FAILED(hr = di->EnumDevices(DI8DEVCLASS_GAMECTRL, enumCallback, NULL, DIEDFL_ATTACHEDONLY)))  return hr;
    
    // Make sure we got a joystick
    if (joystick == NULL){
        printf("Joystick not found.\n");
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    if (FAILED(hr = joystick->SetDataFormat(&c_dfDIJoystick2))) return hr;

    if (FAILED(hr = joystick->SetCooperativeLevel(NULL, DISCL_EXCLUSIVE | DISCL_FOREGROUND))) return hr;

    capabilities.dwSize = sizeof(DIDEVCAPS);

    if (FAILED(hr = joystick->GetCapabilities(&capabilities))) return hr;

    if (FAILED(hr = joystick->EnumObjects(enumAxesCallback, NULL, DIDFT_AXIS)))  return hr;



    if (joystick) {
        joystick->Unacquire();
    }






    return 0;
}
```

Comment: DirectX 8 was like 20 years ago. You sure you want to develop for something that out of date?

Comment: Yes, it was specified to me for a project. @user4581301

Comment: The samples for DirectInput can be found [here](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/master/DirectInput). Do not use DirectInput for keyboard or  mouse input; just use it for legacy joysticks like you are working with. For gamepads, you should consider XInput as well.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I already looked at that link. It didn't help much. I just want to detect a specific joystick and have it be read and displayed on the console. If you must know, the joystick is an Arduino that is programmed to act like a joystick. I don't want to do Serial